# No such key error. ListObjectsCommand AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a folder like this `bucket/folder1/folder2/file.webp`.
I want list all files inside folder2 so I'm using ListObjectsCommand but it's give me `No such key` error code

Here's my code:

```
const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'folder1/folder2/',
  });
await client.send(command)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter Bucket needs to match your actual bucket name. Based on your path I would think your would want to do something like this

```
const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'folder1/folder2/',
  });
await client.send(command)
```

Comment: Also it's recommended to just use 'ListObjectsV2' for future reference. Something to look into.

Comment: I tried your suggest but it's still return me error. I don't know why

Comment: Would you be able to post the full S3 path starting with s3://. If you open any folder on S3 there will be a "Copy S3 Uri" button.

Comment: ```https://sin1.contabostorage.com/a6acdda88e3d403bad0551c36fcdba3f:afang/chapter/6/1/image.webp``` this path?

Comment: base on your suggest I write like this
```const command = new ListObjectsV2Command({
    Bucket: 'afang',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'chapter/6/1/',
  });

  client.send(command, (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
  });```

Comment: Is this stored on S3? Your https address look very unfamiliar.

Comment: yes but I'm using contabo

Comment: after few try I know the issue. I config wrong endpoint. Now it's worked, thank you for helping